# finding index of none and nan in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have an array which looks like:

```
array([[  1.,   2.,   None],
       [ nan,   4.,   5.]])
```

I am trying the following:

```
np.equal(A, None) #works and finds index of None correctly
np.equal(A, np.nan) #doesn't work
np.isnan(A) #errors out
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

How should I approach this, I am trying to find the index of None and nan in a given array.

My final output should look as:

```
array([[False, False,  True],
       [True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: `np.nan` is a proper float, but `None` is an object.  So your array has dtype object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could first [cast the array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) to have dtype float — which will convert the None to NaN. `numpy.isnan` can then be used on this float array.

```
numpy.isnan(A.astype(float))
```